# ¿Cómo puedo manejar múltiples usuarios desde git para subir cambios al repositorio?

Tags: git, github

Buen día, tengo la siguiente duda/problema:

Actualmente tengo dos usuarios independientes para subir cambios de los proyectos al repositorio, es decir, tengo un usuario, para subir en un repositorio proyectos personales y tengo otro usuario, para subir en otro repositorio proyectos laborales.

Actualmente ya genere dos claves `ssh` para cada uno, pero mi problema surge cuando tengo que agregar al `ssh-agent`. Estoy siguiendo la documentación de **GitHub**, específicamente [esta](https://docs.github.com/es/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) parte, pero no entiendo si cada vez que cambio de usuario debo generar una nueva `ssh-agent` o si debo como volver a ejecutar una ya creada para cada llave `ssh`.

Además de esto, tengo configurado como global un correo y nombre de usuario, si yo cambio de usuario, como puedo hacer para que al momento de hacer commit a mis cambios no me aparezcan los datos que ya definí globales sino otro correo y otro nombre.

En resumen:

- ¿Es necesario generar una `ssh-agent` nueva cada vez que haré cambios con otra llave?
- ¿Cómo puedo definir un correo y nombre de usuario diferente al que tengo definido como global? ¿Es posible dejarle predeterminado uno a cada llave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no es necesario lanzar ssh-agent cada vez, a menos que estés remplazando una clave con la otra..

puedes configurar `~/.ssh/config` y los remotes de tus repositorios para decidir qué clave usar en cada caso.

Ejemplo:

```
Host github-empresa
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/usuario/.ssh/clave-empresa
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host github-personal
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/usuario/.ssh/clave-personal
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

y en cada repo:

```
git remote set-url remote git@github-personal:repo.git
git remote set-url remote git@github-empresa:repo.git
```

Si la clave de empresa siempre la usarás para un github enterprise con otro hostname puedes simplemente configurar `Host git.empresa.com` y no hace falta cambiar nada en los repositorios.

Comment: El archivo `~/.ssh/config` sino lo tengo creado, lo creo, ¿verdad?

Además, al configurar ese archivo con cada Host como me lo indicas y poner el git remote set-url en cada repo, ¿eso hace que automáticamente ya tome cada usuario que está especificado con cada llave?

Comment: Exacto. Si el fichero no existe créalo. Si, lo que hace ese fichero es decir al comando ssh que configuración usar. Si tienes una clave ssh en `~/.ssh/my-server-key` puedes usar ese fichero para decirl que cuando hagas ssh a `my.server.com` use es clave. Y asi no tienes que especificarla manualmente.

Comment: Cuando haces `git push origin <branch>` el mira tus remotes para ver a que url debe hacer push. Con el set-url estamos sobreescribiendo la que tenías por un host que no existe. Pero en la config de ssh le dices que ese "host" `github-empresa` resuelva a `github.com` y que use la clave ssh que está configurado. Con esa clave git es capaz de saber quien eres y por lo tanto haces el "cambio de usuario". espero que tenga sentido :)

Comment: Entiendo, adicional a esto, ¿qué significa el `IdentitiesOnly yes`?